# How to have the type of boot detected by the kernel and written to a file (perhaps in /proc)

Tags: boot

This is probably not possible, but I want to know how to have the kernel detect what caused the motherboard to start and possibly store that in a file in the /proc folder.

With "what caused the motherboard to start" I mean if it was because the power button was pressed, because a Wake On Lan signal was received, because of a scheduled boot, or something else.

I need this because I frequently use my iPhone to start my computer when I get home via Wake On Lan, and I have configured Ubuntu to log in automatically so that when I start using my PC it is ready loading and starting everything scheduled to start at login, such as Skype or Steam.

However, when I use WOL to start it, and Skype goes online, people may think I'm there when I'm not and start messaging me but get no reply from me. When I start the PC using the power button I am usually going to use it right after it's logged in, so my skype contacts won't think I'm there when I'm not. So if I could configure it to not start Skype if a WOL signal initated the boot, but do start Skype if the power button initiated the boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way a computer is started is not saved and not passed onto the operating system.

> and Skype goes online, people may think I'm there when I'm not

I would assume it would be less trouble to start Skype with your status set to "off line" or "invisible".

> and start messaging me but get no reply from me.

I do not see a problem here. If you do not respond you are not there.

Comment: Well, ok then. I didn't think it was possible to do it anyway.

Comment: :D  "If you do not respond, you're not there"...  Just that is worthy of an upvote!